# Xampp suddenly showing "MySQL shutdown unexpectedly when I try to turn on mysql"

Tags: xampp

I have used xampp for almost a year now and suddenly i get this error today when I try to turn mysql on. "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method".
Previously, since my new inputs to a table weren't showing in the database I clicked an option to show all the inputs in that table. I got a pop up saying " Do you really want to see all of the rows? For a big table this could make the browser crash." I clicked yes and it showed all my inputs.

Could this be the reason as to why xampp isnt working properly now? If anybody has an idea please tell me.

Edit

Ive managed to get it to work by following instructions on this webpage https://appuals.com/error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/ using the use msql backup folder option. It works now after my doing this process twice. But my worry is that the  error log for mysql shows the following lines. Ive only added a few.

```
2022-08-13 11:44:37 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=305] log sequence number 1659748 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 332445.

2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"

2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\Users\Desktop\installxampphere\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\Users\Desktop\installxampphere\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2022-08-13 11:44:40 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=9] log sequence number 1963404 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 332445.

2022-08-13 11:44:40 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.21 started; log sequence number 332436; transaction id 4047

2022-08-13 11:44:40 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=66, page number=0] log sequence number 1750880 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 332445.

2022-08-13 11:44:40 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

2022-08-13 11:44:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Users\Desktop\installxampphere\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

2022-08-13 11:44:41 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=66, page number=1] log sequence number 1749284 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 332445.

2022-08-13 11:44:41 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

2022-08-13 11:44:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=243] log sequence number 1551860 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 332445.

2022-08-13 11:44:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

2022-08-13 11:44:41 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2022-08-13 11:44:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220813 11:44:41

2022-08-13 11:44:42 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Everything starts up okay for the moment but is there anything for me to worry about in these logs? Im clueless as to what these lines mean.

Comment: Could you post the LAST 100 lines of your error log for analysis?

Comment: I managed to get it working by following the Use mysql backup folder process on this webpage "https://appuals.com/error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/". The first time I did this and ran the server, it worked,  i then put it off and ran again. It Crashed. Repeated the process in webpage stated and now it works again. Im just hoping it does not crash again. Im guessing a file got corrupted some how. @WilsonHauck

Comment: Ive posted a few of the lines that come up now, the thing works but the logs say my database might be corrupt. @WilsonHauck

Comment: Additional URL that describes  https://severalnines.com/blog/my-mysql-database-corrupted-what-do-i-do-now/   when running with linux hosted system.  NOT DIRECTLY applicable for you since your xampp is running under Windows management. For educational purposes only for your broadened knowledge.